# Issues with sliding rtl and ltr in IE 7

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple div sliding animation(built from scratch no thrid party) which works fine in IE10,FF,Chrome but in IE 7 it doesn't work.Even in IE 8 it works.

HTMl

```
<div class="aboutus">
    <div class="margin_slide"></div>
    <div class="about_container">CLick here to go to some content div which is next div and this div will go to the extreme left.</div>
    <div class="whatwedo_container">Some Content div.Click here to go to previous div.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.about_container {
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    background:#ddd;
    height:300px
}
.whatwedo_container {
    position: absolute;
    right: -100%;
    width: 300px;
    background:#000;
    height:300px;
    color:#fff;
    top:0;
}
.aboutus {
    background: #20407B;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.margin_slide {
  margin: auto 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 1100px;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.about_container').click(function () {
    var $slideupto = $('.margin_slide');
    var ending_right = $(window).width() - $slideupto.offset().left;
    $('.about_container').animate({
        right: ending_right
    }, 600);
    var rightpos = $(window).width() - ($(".margin_slide").offset().left + $('.whatwedo_container').outerWidth());

    $('.whatwedo_container').animate({
        right: rightpos
    }, 800);
});

$('.whatwedo_container').click(function () {
    $('.about_container').animate({
        right: '0'
    }, 600);
     $('.whatwedo_container').animate({
        right: '-100%'
    }, 600);
});
```

Jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/uv6Q5/7/

IN ie 7 the div2 scrolls from right to left and takes the position of div 1 and div goes to further right.But when I click the div 2 to get back the div 1,the div 1 comes back in it's own position but div 2 doesn't go back to it's original position.

Any help please.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You still need to support IE7? May God have mercy on your soul.

Comment: Hahaha well said.There are still few people who use IE7/8.God needs to call and ask them to upgrade the browser.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, for your animation function:

```
$('.whatwedo_container').animate({
        right: -($(window).width())
}, 600);
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nevster/xFPN3/2/).

Comment: Thanks Nev.It works in all browser except IE7.Did you try with IE7?

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra Yeah I've tried this code in IE7. Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nevster/xFPN3/2/embedded/result/) work in IE7?

Comment: Yes I tried in IE7 but still not working.Is it working from your end?

Comment: hmm..then I guess a parent div in original html code is creating the problem.let me check.

Comment: Hey Nev thanks mate.It is working now. I have accepted your answer.As guessed the parent div was creating the problem.Thanks once again.